# implementing javascript library in rails app

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

This has proven a difficult thing to Google. I know it seems like it should be easy to Google.

I'm trying to understand how to implement nice libraries like [gmaps.js](http://hpneo.github.com/gmaps/examples/basic.html).

application.html.erb:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag :defaults %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "gmaps" %>
```

Not sure if both of those are necessary. I have gmaps.js in my /vendor/assets/javascripts folder, using rails 3.2.3. I would love to know if the former handles it.

app/assets/javascripts/indexmap.js:

```
new GMaps({
    div: '#map',
    lat: -12.043333,
    lng: -77.028333
});
```

index.html.erb:

```
<div id="themap">
    <%= javascript_include_tag("indexmap") %>
</div>
```

application.css:

```
#themap{
  display: block;
  width: 95%;
  height: 350px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 5px 20px #ccc;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 5px 20px #ccc;
  box-shadow: 0px 5px 20px #ccc;
}
```

All I get is a blank box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try ":gmaps" instead of "gmaps".

Also, try right-click inspect on the box, and see if JS is throwing an error in Chrome's inspector.

OK- update, figured it out.

You need to use Google Maps and JQuery to get this to work. There is no CSS per se, you need to establish the object in a jQuery document ready block. I've [zipped a sample of this working  (in a basic rails app)](http://www.banane.com/test4.zip).

Essentially, include jQuery and Maps above the gMaps.js, and then include some JS:

```
<server type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  map = new GMaps({
    div: '#map',
    lat: -12.043333,
    lng: -77.028333
  });
});
</script>
<div id="map" style="height:200px;width:200px;"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks. The colon didn't help. This is the html generated, as seen in inspector:  <script src="/assets/indexmap.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>

Comment: ah, the include tag should be "indexmap" (name of the js file), in quotes, you were right about that.

Comment: No error in the JS console. I feel like my mistake is in trying to use the javascript_include_tag in the div. My real question is what I need to put there to yield the map.

Comment: Yeah, acc. to the gmaps.js site, you just need the CSS id and it should "just work" (famous last words). (so take out the javascript_include_tag in the div)

Comment: No, I'm still missing something big. I suspect that new GMaps(...); isn't enough javascript in indexmap.js.

Comment: There is some funky ordering sequence with rails and JS - check the page source of your file in Chrome and see where indexmap is ordered in re: to other JS files

Comment: You can also attach your whole project and I can debug.